# python datetime timestrp function error

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to get the datetime from a txt file. In this file the time is presented with `[` and `]` around it.

I know the first line is always a timestamp. But when I try to get the datetime with strptime I get an error message.

I have searched other solutions. But don't seem to find any that match my mistake.

**Code:**

```
FileYSI = open(FilenameYSI,'r')
TimeStampYSI = [next(FileYSI)for x in xrange(1)]

print TimeStampYSI[0]
if TimeStampYSI[0][0] == '['
    TimeFP = time.strptime(TimeStampYSI[0],'[%y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f]\n')
```

**Error:**

```
[2015-09-22,08:10:00.600000]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/brondert/Documents/realtime_data_aquadrone/trunk/src/MergeLogs.py", line 129, in <module>
    MergeLogs("test")
  File "C:/Users/brondert/Documents/realtime_data_aquadrone/trunk/src/MergeLogs.py", line 92, in MergeLogs
    TimeFP = time.strptime(TimeStampYSI[0],'[%y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.600000]\n')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 467, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '[2015-09-22,08:10:00.600000]\n' does not match format '[%y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.600000]\n'
```

Comment: The code doesn't match the error message `time.strptime(TimeStampYSI[0],'[%y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.600000]\n')` isn't in your code.

Answer (score 5):

The format for 4-digit years is `%Y` (capital Y) not `%y`  , you should use that, Example -

```
TimeFP = time.strptime(TimeStampYSI[0],'[%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f]\n')
```

Demo -

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime('[2015-09-22,08:10:00.600000]\n','[%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f]\n')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=8, tm_min=10, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=265, tm_isdst=-1)
```

The `%y` (small y) format is for 2-digit years.

Another thing, you are currently using `time` module , you would get a `struct_time` as result of `strptime` , but if you want `datetime` , you should use the `datetime` module . Example -

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(TimeStampYSI[0],'[%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f]\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

`%y` is for 2-digit year. For 4-digit you have to use `%Y`

```
TimeFP = time.strptime(TimeStampYSI[0],'[%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f]\n')
```